# Natbib author-year citation style in the tufte-book class

Tags: bibliographies, document-classes, natbib, tufte

I'm using the [tufte-book class](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/) and I like it so much!

However, I'd like to have the references in the natbib-way, so that I 
can use both textual (\citep) and parenthetical (\citep) citations. 
I have a lot of citations, and I don't want them to take all the room 
in the page margin (tufte class extensively uses side notes).

All I'd like to have is a working natbib reference style. How can I modify the [tufte-common.def](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/source/checkout) file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class only redefines the `\cite` command, you can use `\citet` and `\citep` as normal. It works in a document that I have using the package.