# List the citation key shown by \citep in the references.

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, hyphenation

Some months ago, I asked a question regarding bibliography hyphenation issue [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437/line-breaking-or-hyphenation-of-references-in-apalike).
In a nutshell, when I was having problems with the hyphenation of the citation keys in the text, I included the `natbib` package and the problem was solved. However, the list of references at the end of the article does not show the key that appears in the text as before.

Here is an example:

With the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

asd asd Hello world \citep{SaCouto:2010:HemodynamicBirth},
\citep{SaCouto:2010:HemodynamicBirth},
\citep{SaCouto:2010:HemodynamicBirth}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{fullbiblio}

\end{document}
```

I get:
[image: with natbib]

---

When commenting the `natbib` package, and changing `\citep` to `\cite`, I get:
[image: without natbib]

---

What I would like is:

- Correct hyphenation (possible when including `natbib`)
- That the references include the key that is shown in the text (possible when not including `natbib`). This key should be [Lastname, year].

So my question is, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the point of showing the citation key (other than adding needless clutter to the bibliography)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to your preample:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{%
\if\relax\@extra@b@citeb\relax\else
\@ifundefined{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{}{%
\@namedef{br@#2}{\@nameuse{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}}}\fi
\@ifundefined{b@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{\def\NAT@num{}}{\NAT@parse{#2}}%
\item[\hfil\hyper@natanchorstart{#2\@extra@b@citeb}\citep{#2}%
\hyper@natanchorend]%
\NAT@ifcmd#1(@)(@)\@nil{#2}}
\makeatother
```

Source: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-07/msg00540.html

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I was looking for! I did not like the identation so I redefined `\thebibliography` as well, as shown on this link: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=9048&start=0

Answer (score 2):

I had [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/natbib-author-year-citation-style-in-the-tufte-book-class) some times ago. Natbib does not put the citation keys in the reference section as a default.

The couple author+year should be enough to pick out the correct reference.

One way to do what you are asking is getting hands on the .bst file. I know it can be a little tricky, but I think that the LaTeX Companion may help in this case (I recently edited the `palinnat.bst` file with a trial-and error technique, and get what I want).

Comment: I agree that author+year should be enough, but I prefer showing the citation key. Many publications do this and I think it is easier to search the references.

Comment: did you already try the `numbers` option?

Comment: Yes. But this way the citation key is not Lastname-year (I realize now that my question should clarify this)

Answer (score 1):

Taking the same idea that @jpz presented here's a different version. With `\citep` there's a problem if you use `hyperref`.

This is the workaround I've came up with:

```
\makeatletter

\def\mysplit#1(#2)#3\@nil{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
{\def\mycitep{#1}}
{\def\mycitep{#1, #2}}
}

\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{%
\mysplit#1\@nil
\if\relax\@extra@b@citeb\relax\else
\@ifundefined{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{}{%
\@namedef{br@#2}{\@nameuse{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}}}\fi
\@ifundefined{b@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{\def\NAT@num{}}{\NAT@parse{#2}}%
\item[\hfil\hyper@natanchorstart{#2\@extra@b@citeb}{[{\mycitep}]}%
\hyper@natanchorend]%
\NAT@ifcmd#1(@)(@)\@nil{#2}}
\makeatother
```

I hope it's helpful for others

Comment: Greetings! Please see a [new posting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274377/5001) that's related to your answer. Can you help out the OP?