# How can I use natbib and make my reference list resemble apalike?

Tags: bibtex, line-breaking, natbib, urls, apa-style

My question is related to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4158/list-the-citation-key-shown-by-citep-in-the-references) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437/line-breaking-or-hyphenation-of-references-in-apalike), but I could not yet find a satisfying answer. I will use the same example from this post.

I like the `apalike` reference style but I have trouble with breaking long references in the text. With the suggested `natbib` package and using `citep`, I get the references to break all right. However, I do not like the bibliography when using `natbib`, because (1) the reference key is not displayed, (2) first names are spelled out and (3) URLs are displayed.

With the following bibtex file

```
@Article{citeme1,
  author =       {Longlastname, Longfirstname and Helloworld E. Xample },
  title =        {A Title},
  journal =      {A journal},
  year =         {2009}
}
@Article{citeme2,
  author =       {Hofstadter, L. and Cooper, S.},
  title =        {Experiences with a roommate that has Asperger syndrome},
  journal =      {The Big Bang Journal},
  year =         {2010},
  url = {http://u.rl},
}
@Article{citeme3,
  author =       {Cooper, Sheldon and Koothrappali, Rajesh and Wolowitz, Howard},
  title =        {Another example},
  journal =      {Another journal},
  year =         2010
}
```

I get the following reference list when using `apalike` (of course, in my document, the references are not broken nicely):

[image]

This would be exactly what I want. However, of course the references in my text are not broken appropriately.

When using `natbib` and the expression in the preamble suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4158/list-the-citation-key-shown-by-citep-in-the-references):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{%
\if\relax\@extra@b@citeb\relax\else
\@ifundefined{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{}{%
\@namedef{br@#2}{\@nameuse{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}}}\fi
\@ifundefined{b@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{\def\NAT@num{}}{\NAT@parse{#2}}%
\item[\hfil\hyper@natanchorstart{#2\@extra@b@citeb}\citep{#2}%
\hyper@natanchorend]%
\NAT@ifcmd#1(@)(@)\@nil{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a paragraph with normal line breaking and hyphenation, isn't it? 
Yes! It is. 

This is paragraph that does not break well when citing \citep{citeme1},
or even \citep{citeme1, citeme2, citeme3}.  
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{f}
\end{document}
```

then I get the following reference list:

[image]

in which the first and third reference has full names and the second doesn't (because the full names are not in the bibtex entry). Also, the second reference still has the URL.

My question is: How can I use `natbib` for nice line breaking in the references in the text and get a reference list that resembles the `apalike` reference list (with keys, letters for first names and no URLs)?

Comment: You might like to try `biblatex` and its APA implementation `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: Thank you, `biblatex-apa` looks like a nice package, but I have not yet managed to install it on my ubuntu machine. I now found a workaround by using `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}` to get all names abbreviated and to parse out the url fields in my bibtex file.

Comment: Well, unfortunately ubuntu ships out quite old LaTeX distributions, so you might be better off without `biblatex`.

Comment: For Ubuntu, updating tex is easy: Uninstall the ubuntu package and use [install-tl-ubuntu](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu). Then, one can follow the instructions given at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/9075 to update the tex live distribution.

Comment: @user1981275 Does `biblatex-apa` work with ubuntu (three years lateer ^^)? Does the package solved your problem? If yes maybe you could write an answer...