# natbib: custom biblabel ignores leftmargin

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, natbib

1. Main question; left margin: This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5772/90444) provides the code to style the bibliography label in a desired fashion. However, the new biblabel ignores the left margin of the page. Since I do not really understand what the code snippet does I'm not able to adapt it to my needs. NOTE: actually I would like to use this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70359/90444) to the same question (it suppresses the hyperlink in the biblabel), but unfortunately I can not make it work with my MWE while it works fine with my actual tex document.
2. Secondary question; bold biblabel: The biblabel should be bold to match the desired bibstyle. a slightly modified abbrvnat.bst is used, the MWE with `abbrvnat` should be ok as example, as far as I understand...

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% bibliography
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setlength\bibhang{1cm} % adjust 2nd(+following) line indentation

% hyperlinks in PDFs
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

% generate bibfile                          
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@ARTICLE{Author1900,
  author = {Author, Andrew and Author, Burt},
  title = {Very short Title},
  journal = {Best Journal},
  year = {1900},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--3},
  number = {7},
  month = jan,
  issn = {1234-5678},
  publisher = {Best Publisher Ltd.},
  timestamp = {1900.01.01},
  url = {www.nonsense.url}
}
\end{filecontents}

% set format of bibitem in reference list
\makeatletter
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{%
   \if\relax\@extra@b@citeb\relax\else
      \@ifundefined{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{}{%
        \@namedef{br@#2}{\@nameuse{br@#2\@extra@b@citeb}}}
   \fi
   \@ifundefined{b@#2\@extra@b@citeb}{\def\NAT@num{}}{\NAT@parse{#2}}%
   \item[\hfil\hyper@natanchorstart{#2\@extra@b@citeb}%
      \citep{#2}%
      \hyper@natanchorend]%
   \NAT@ifcmd#1(@)(@)\@nil{#2}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

This is a simple citation \citep{Author1900}.

\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just out of curiosity: What may be the reason for wanting to show the citation call-out strings alongside the typeset entries? As far as I can tell, there's no discernible information content in showing the citation call-out string, and doing so does add quite a bit of visual clutter.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I have been "silent observer" to TeX.SE for years. The citation in my thesis document (different from the MWE) gives the first author and the year only, like: [1stAuthor, 1900]. This limits visual clutter while providing a bit of additional information when reading the text without turning pages back and forth. The matching biblabel is then required to allow non-electronic-readers to find the reference easily.

Comment: is nobody able to give me at least a hint how to solve this?

Comment: I did look at code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`; I'm afraid I not able to understand it sufficiently well to let me figure out which instructions do what. Is there any chance in you contacting the original author of the cdoe and asking for some help?

Comment: @Mico: the original answer-author is no longer active, another answerer (with hyperref solved) is still active but my reputation is to low to add a comment and I didn't find anything to leave a personal message...

Comment: I've taken the liberty of tweaking your code for readability and have posted an associated screenshot. Let's see if any other users of this site take note.

Comment: I've also left a comment under @G66LCT earlier answer; let's see if he/she takes note.